# How to send mail in zend with linode sendmail server

Tags: php, zend-framework

My project is set-up on linode web-server and developed in zend framework 1.12. 
I am trying to send mail, By using zend_mail() function but not able to succeed. I does not give error but also can not able to send mail. While checking server configuration in phpinfo I found that the server has send mail library with directive

sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

My code is as below

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setBodyText('This is the text of the mail.')
->setFrom('somebody@example.com', 'Some Sender')
->addTo('somebody_else@example.com', 'Some Recipient')
->setSubject('TestSubject')
->send();
```

Can anybody help me regarding any changes in above code

Comment: If you just try and send an email using PHP's `mail()` function, does that work? (This will help narrow down where the problem lies.)

Comment: @TimFountain No PHP's mail() function also does not working :(

Comment: Does this help you: https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=3712&highlight=sendmail+iptables ?